# Add a port to url Existing i using google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I 'm trying add a port to url/ip existing `http//181.48.32.122.` 
This is the port 3001 and i want it add to ip `http//181.48.32.122`
i am using this way `http//181.48.32.122:3001` but i get a error it say "The URL `http://181.48.32.122:3001` you entered is redundant. Please check the "Registering authorized URLs" link below and remove the redundant URL." 
i read the documentation of Registering Authorized URLs and there is a example that said just must add the port to de url existing example `http://example.com:8080`

what i should correcting?

i wait for your answers thanks

Comment: What has this got to do with Google Maps?

Comment: i buy a licence of the google maps and need using this license in my web side

Comment: Google Maps Enterprise(Paid version) comes with support